# Why do I get a ChunkedEncodingError in Python when using requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests, pubmed

I try to query this API `https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi`
with these params `?db=mesh&id=68016019`
So the whole URL is `https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=mesh&id=68016019`
When executing this in Postman everything's fine and the output is as expected:

```
1: Survival Analysis
A class of statistical procedures for estimating the survival function (function 
of time, starting with a population 100% well at a given time and providing the
percentage of the population still well at later times). The survival analysis is
then used for making inferences about the effects of treatments, prognostic
etc.
*
*
*
```

BUT when I try to query this via requests module in Python I receive this error:

```
("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))
```

So what am I doing exactly? I just fire this command:

```
response2 = requests.get(
        "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=mesh&id=" + str(id))
```

(The id is converted to a string as I got some issues when I don't do it.) For 99.9% of the cases this approach is absolutely fine but then there comes this 0.1% cases I am lost. I do not get what this ChunkedEncodingError is about.

Is this error coming from the API or from my script?
Can please someone help?

I tried to query this in Postman -> it works
I tried to execute the same query from my script in a complete new script -> it works (???)

but why not in my original script?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but (a) `id` is the name of a Python built-in, which means if you use `id` as a variable and you haven't previously defined it, it will mysteriously work but with an unexpected value. Consider renaming it to something else (e.g., `article_id`); (b) instead of `"url?id=" + str(article_id)`, consider using an f-string, e.g. `f"url?id={article_id}"`.

Comment: But w/r/t your question, are you getting the chunked encoding error consistently for particular urls? Or if you request the same url multiple times will it generally work but occasionally throw the error?

Comment: Thank you @larsks. I just changed all the mentioned parts from your first answer.
w/r/t your second answer, I'll get these errors randomly. It seems like sometimes it works and sometimes not. Because the same URL works if I try it manually in Postman or if I put this snippet in an extra file. I mean you could try it out on your end. Not auth needed. It will most likely work on your side I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I'm unable to reproduce the problem you're asking about. Maybe the correct solution is just to implement some retry logic specific to the ChunkedEncodingError exception.

Comment: Do you have any tips for me? Like do I have to implement error handling or what were you thinking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are occasionally getting a `ChunkedEncodingError`, you can implement some retry logic in that case:

Something like this would retry a given URL 3 times (with a 1 second pause between each retry):

```
import requests
import time

article_id=68016019

for attempt in range(3):
    try:
        res = requests.get(
            f"https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entre/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=mesh&id={article_id}")
        break
    except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve url")
```

You would obviously want to implement better error handling than simply printing a messsage and continuing.